# Handling nested DER, packed into OCTET STRINGs, in pyasn1

Tags: pyasn1

Here's how RFC 5280 defines an X.509 extension field:

```
Extension  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     extnID      OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
     critical    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
     extnValue   OCTET STRING
                 -- contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value
                 -- corresponding to the extension type identified
                 -- by extnID
     }
```

When I use the pyasn1 decoder, I'll get an object `foo` whose `foo['extnValue'].asOctets()` can be further decoded, with another call to the decoder, using the schema appropriate to `foo['extnID']`.

**Question:** supposing that there's one special `extnID` in my application, is it possible in pyasn1 to define a schema that (a) doesn't accept any OBJECT IDENTIFIER, only the special one; and (b) steps past the OCTET STRING wrapper to decode the payload according to the appropriate special "sub-schema" ?

I can do this by special-case logic in the code, but I'd prefer to define a special-case schema if that is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [OpenType](http://snmplabs.com/pyasn1/pyasn1/type/opentype/opentype.html) for `extnValue` type definition. When you pass decoder the map of `extnID` -> `ASN.1 type`, the decoder then will step past the outermost `extnValue` wrapper trying to decode its contents.

Here's a quick example:

```
openType = opentype.OpenType(
        'id',
        {1: univ.Integer(),
         2: univ.OctetString()}
    )
    self.s = univ.Sequence(
        componentType=namedtype.NamedTypes(
            namedtype.NamedType('id', univ.Integer()),
            namedtype.NamedType('blob', univ.Any(), openType=openType)
        )
    )
```

Make sure to pass `decodeOpenTypes=True` argument to the `decode()` function if you want the decoder to unwrap these open types.

BTW, if you look at the [pyasn1-modules](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/blob/master/pyasn1_modules/rfc5280.py#L1590), that map is already there. If you use these definitions and just pass `decodeOpenTypes=True` keyword argument to decoder, you should get your extensions unwrapped.

There is no ready-made way to fail the decoder on unknown `extnID`. You can probably model that my giving it your own map (perhaps based on `dict`) which would fail on unsuccessful `key in my_map` operation.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you.  However, I don't understand enough of `pyasn1` to really make sense of your `ExtensionAttribute` class in pyasn1-modules.  Would you mind providing a detailed breakdown of that class definition, including some detail on the subtyping and tagging operations, for expository purposes?  (I can post that as a new question if you'd prefer.)